# Удаление репозитоия с github, работа с git

Tags: git, github

1. Как с github удалить ненужный репозиторий?
2. Как вставлять текст из буфера в командную строку в git, чтобы было
   НЕ как на фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: shift + insert? ПКМ по заголвку -> вставить?

Comment: @pavel, а что по удалению репозитория с github?

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/23914426/5951529** . Не так давно я искал способы удаления через терминал — не нашёл. Спасибо.

Comment: [**Здесь**](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/494) можете высказаться или хотя бы поставить плюс, чтобы добавили возможность удаления репозиториев через терминал. Например, у меня множество форков накопилось, долго поодиночке их удалять. Спасибо.

Comment: А правая или средняя клавиша мыши не всавляет?

Comment: Для вас "папка" и "репозиторий" это синонимы?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет

Comment: @bsuart2017, так почему тогда заголовок не соответствует тексту вопроса?